# Location service not getting called from Oreo

Tags: android, performance, android-location, android-8.0-oreo, android-jobscheduler

I was starting `LocationService` with `startService()` command, but since i learnt that Oreo will not entertain this service when app is in background, I switched over to `JobSchedular`,

I tested the app in `lollipop` and `JobSchedular` worked just fine, but in Oreo, it does not run `LocationService`

I put `break point` in `onCreate()` method of LocationService, and it just does not go there.

This is what I am doing.

**MainActivity**

It executes following code, but does not react to `LocationUpdateService.class`

```
    public void initLocationJob(){

        JobInfo jobInfo;
        JobScheduler jobScheduler;

        ComponentName componentName= new ComponentName(this, LocationUpdateService.class);
        JobInfo.Builder builder= new JobInfo.Builder(11, componentName);

        builder.setPeriodic(5000);
        builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY);
        builder.setPersisted(true);

        jobInfo= builder.build();
        jobScheduler= (JobScheduler) getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);


        jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
}
```

**LocationUpdateService**

```
public class LocationUpdateService extends JobService implements
        LocationListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        IServiceResponse {



    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        if (isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {

            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();

            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {

        Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand: ");
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(BACKGROUND_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(BACKGROUND_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

        this.params= params;

        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        Log.d("JobStopped", "JobStopped");
        return true;
    }

 @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
     //Get current Lat/lng and send it to server
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is with following code:

```
JobInfo.Builder builder= new JobInfo.Builder(11, componentName);
builder.setPeriodic(5000);
```

Starting from Android N, JobScheduler works with a minimum periodic of 15 mins. Frequency of 5 seconds is too frequent and is inappropriate.

Comment: Thanks @Sagar, I will try this, but shouldn't it run this service for 1 time atleast?

Comment: You have no control over when within this interval this job will be executed, only the guarantee that it will be executed at most once within this interval

Comment: I tried this on Nougat device, and it successfully send data after 10 minutes, but oreo did not send any update, may be because i don't have physical oreo device, and i am testing it in emulator.

Comment: @Kirmani88 Thanks for updating. Should not behave drastically different on Emulator and Real Device. But would be worth to check it.

Comment: It calls `onCreate` and `onStartJob` but does not calls `onLocationChanged` method on `Oreo`

Comment: @Kirmani88 Check [Background Location Limit](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits) document for more details

Comment: @Kirmani88 for the scope of your question, if you feel it was helpful then remember to mark it as accepted, so that others can benefit too.